# Setting the value of a global variable from inside a function

Tags: function-construction

I am trying to set the value of a global variable `X` from inside a function.

I want the value of this variable to change when the function is called. The function will also return the string `"pass"` when called.

Here is the code:

```
function[] := (
   X = 10;
   Return["pass"];
   );
```

However, when I set a new value for X in the function, then call the function

```
function[]
```

and then call `X`, I get the OLD value of `X`, implying that `X` was never changed.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suggest you restart the kernel and try again.

Comment: You must reevaluate the definition of the function.
That said, changing a global from a local context (the function) in this way is just not good practice.

Comment: To analyse the problem you can evaluate `??function` and see if there is something abnormal. You can paste screenshot in the question above too.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate this in a new session with a clean notebook.

```
x = 42;
function[] := (
  x = 10;
  "pass"
  )
```

Note that you do not need to use `Return`. A Wolfram Language function always returns the last expression it evaluates.

Evaluate

```
Dynamic[x]
```

You should get the output `42`, the current value of `x`. Now evaluate

```
function[]
```

You should get the output `pass` and the output below `Dynamic[x]` should change to `10`. `Dynamic` is very useful for tracking the changes to global variables when debugging.